# How to build task 'generate_secret_token'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rubygems

I'm getting this error when I run:

```
rake generate_secret_token

rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'generate_secret_token'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

when I run full trace

```
 rake generate_secret_token --trace
```

this is what I'm getting;

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: add your rake task code

Comment: im trying to migrate a database.

Comment: do you want to run migration or task?

Comment: this is my Rakefile.

**require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)**

**FormsgenUi::Application.load_tasks**

Comment: will you please update your file which you are trying to run

Comment: yes i want to run migration.

Comment: for migrating you just use rake db:migrate

Comment: can u please give me an idea or an example how to update the file. i check the rakefile of my redmine and its the same with the rakefile of _formsgen_ (what im trying to install now). i was able to successfully migrate database on redmine before without updating the rakefile. this time i dont know what's wrong.. 

please be patient with me. im completely noob. 

TIA

Comment: any gem you are using?

Comment: Thanks @user123. i was able to migrate by running "rake db:migrate". 

but, is it okay if i don't generate a secret token?

Comment: i'll get back at you on Monday. I appreciate your help.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your rake task has the following format:

```
namespace :your_namespace do
  desc 'Description for rake task'
  task generate_secret_token: :environment do
  end
end
```

While running rake task, run as 'rake namespace:generate_secret_token'

Comment: Thanks @Adnan Devops, i was abe to run the task by adding this to my Rakefile     'namespace :formsgen do
  desc 'generate secret token'
  task generate_secret_token: :environment do
  end
end
'

Comment: ok good that it helped your cause. Could you please accept this answer if it solved your issue

Comment: yeah! i still have lots to learn. this  site is a big help for guys like me.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
rake db:migrate
```

This command is used to run your db migrations.

```
rake task_name
```

This command is used to run your rake tasks which you have written lib/tasks folder

Comment: thanks @user123 for the help. i was able to run by adding a task  to my Rakefile as what adnan had suggested.

i appreciate all your help.